# jelly: Create a table using JSON object

Tags: java, json, jenkins, groovy, jelly

I am trying to build a `Jenkins Post build plugin` where I have to process `JSON` file (contains test results) and show it in `tabular format` in `Jenkins` once build is executed.

Following are the steps done till now:

1. Created Jenkins plugin
2. Able to retrieve JSON file content and read it as Google gson `JSONElement`.
3. Built `BuildAction` (extends Action) to show the results.
4. In `index.jelly` (`view` for `BuildAction`) corresponding to `BuildAction`, trying to show each record in JSON file, as a row.

`JSON` File sample:

```
{
    "records": [{
        "objectProps": {
            "OTYPE": "TEST",
            "NAME": "testMethodError",

        }
    },
    {
        "objectProps": {
            "OTYPE": "TEST",
            "NAME": "testMethodFail",
        }
    }]
}
```

BuildAction class:

```
public class BuildAction implements Action {
    private JsonElement results;
    private Run<?, ?> build;
    TaskListener listener;

    // this value referred as `it.results` in `index.jelly`
    public JsonArray getResults(){
        return results.getAsJsonObject().get("records").getAsJsonArray();
    }

}
```

current `index.jelly` for above `BuildAction` class

```
<?jelly escape-by-default='true'?>
<j:jelly xmlns:j="jelly:core" xmlns:st="jelly:stapler" xmlns:l="/lib/layout">
    <l:layout>
        <st:include it="${it.build}" page="sidepanel.jelly"/>
        <l:main-panel>
            <table> Test - Wise Results
             <j:forEach items="${it.results}" var="i">
                <tr><td>Test case name: ${i}</td></tr>
             </j:forEach>
            </table>         
        </l:main-panel>

    </l:layout>
</j:jelly>
```

**Actual behaviour:**

As of now, `${results}` value is of `JSONArray` type. [forEach](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-jelly/tags.html#core:forEach) in jelly, I am able iterate over and get the record using var `i` (syntax `${i}`). `i` refers to each record in `records` JSONArray. Now, I want to access `objectProps.NAME` field using `i`, I don't know the syntax in Jelly to achieve the same.

**Expected behaviour:**

I wan to iterate through `records` array in JSON file and each child/jsonObject as one table row (and its values as corresponding columns).

something similar to this (to access `NAME` value):

```
<j:forEach items="${it.results}" var="i">
   <tr><td>Test case name: ${i}."objectProps"."NAME"</td></tr>
</j:forEach>
```

Need help in building the `table` out of a `JSON` using `Jelly`. Any other way of achieving the same also welcome (please post code samples when suggesting the same).

**Note:** `Groovy` related answer also welcome as `Jenkins` support both `Jelly and Groovy` for `View`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am interested in solving you problem, but might not have a 100% certain answer as I can't test locally.

Have you tried to use `${i.objectProps.NAME}`or `${i."objectProps"."NAME"}` instead of `${i}."objectProps"."NAME"`in your example?

You could also see if `g:evaluate` is available, as jelly might not evaluate your variable without explicitly telling it to do so. You can find some documentation on `g:evaluate` [here.](http://wiki.servicenow.com/index.php?title=Jelly_Tags#evaluate)

Comment: First, I must appreciate your enthusiasm. and yes, it worked for me. `${i.objectProps.NAME}` got me the value in double quotes (eg: `Test case name: "testMethodError"` ). 1. Is there any way to remove them and display only content?  I think `g:evaluate` is specific to `serviceNow` company but not part of `Apache Jelly`. 2. Are you sure we can use this? I tired this. Though it did not throw any error, but executing it as `plain text` instead of `javascript`.

Comment: 1) Judging from what I've seen everything inside `${}` is executed as groovy code. I am not aware where these double quotes could come from, you could try to remove them there with something like `${i.objectProps.NAME.replace(/neededRegEx/,"")}`. This would work if they are in your data, if jelly adds them, then it could possibly be more complicated.
2) I was not sure if it's work, but it really seems to be specific to `serviceNow`.

Comment: ok. thanks. I'll try it out. can't offer bounty till one day completes once it starts. so, will offer once I get the privilege. One more challenge I am facing is that, trying to convert `index.jelly` script to `index.groovy`. But in the line `st.include(it : it.build, page : "sidepanel.jelly")`, causing the Null Pointer exception. If you know, can you please post the `groovy` version of above `index.jelly` ?

Comment: Why are you trying to convert it to a `.groovy` file? I have only worked on plugins that used `.jelly`as template files, so I am not sure where your Null Pointer is coming from :(

Comment: ok. because `groovy` is more flexible compared to `jelly`. I can write `if, for, while and other programming things` in simple manner where `jelly` seems a little bit trickier for me.

Comment: True, I think most jenkins ressources you will find online are using `jelly` for the frontend. And you can still do all these things in jelly, just in a different syntax.